# How to style an iframe after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to style to box that my iframe will load, adding box-shadow and a height, but I don't want that both of them are styled before the user clicks the link, because there will be a blank box with placing a high height.

So how do I style the iframe after the user clicks the button/link?

```html
<a href="https://google.com" onclick="document.getElementById('load-chat');" target="load-chat">Load the page</a>
 
<iframe style="box-shadow:0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4; border-radius: 10px;" frameborder="0" id="load-chat" name="load-chat" scrolling="0" width="200" height="400"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function styleMyiFrame() 
        {
            document.getElementById("load-chat").style.boxShadow = "0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4";
            document.getElementById("load-chat").height = "500px";
            document.getElementById("load-chat").width = "500px";
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://google.com" onclick="styleMyiFrame();" target="load-chat" id="my">Load the page</a>

    <iframe frameborder="0" id="load-chat" name="load-chat" scrolling="0"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have the iFrame not visible on page then when the user clicks the link the iFrame is visible? If so below is method on how to do so. Note, IE9 doesn't support this.

```css
.iframe {width:0px; height:0px;display:none;}
.styled-iframe {box-shadow:0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4; border-radius: 10px; width:200px; height:200px;display:block}
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script>
function styleIframe() {
var open = document.getElementById("load-chat"); 
open.classList.add("styled-iframe");
var hide = document.getElementById("button");
hide.classList.add("hide");
}
</script> 

<a href="https://google.com" onclick="document.getElementById(&apos;load-chat&apos;);styleIframe();" target="load-chat" id="button" >Load the page</a>
 
<iframe frameborder="0" id="load-chat" class="iframe" name="load-chat" scrolling="0" />
```

Comment: This is close to what I wanted.. Is there any way to trigger this event just like I did adding display:none to the button? Without having to create a separated function for that..

Comment: I edited my answer to hide the button onclick, but no I using a separate function is the cleanest simplest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<a id="lnkLoad" href="https://google.com" target="load-chat">Load the page</a>    

<iframe frameborder="0" id="load-chat" name="load-chat" scrolling="0" width="200" height="200" />
```

**JS**

```
$('#lnkLoad').click(function() {
  $('#load-chat').attr("style", "box-shadow:0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4; border-radius: height:400px;");
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/64avjeq6/2)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do the way I wanted (all inline):

```css
.mywidget {
  width: 250px
}
```

```html
<div class="mywidget">
  <a href="https://google.com" onclick="document.getElementById('load-chat');
document.getElementById('load-chat').height = '400px';
document.getElementById('load-chat').style.boxShadow = '0px 3px 15px #e4e4e4';
document.getElementById('load-chat').style.borderRadius = '15px';" target="load-chat">Load my iframe
  </a>

  <iframe frameborder="0" id="load-chat" name="load-chat" scrolling="0" width="200px" />

</div>
```